# Bidimenstional array with 3 arrays inside to a 3 single ones php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to convert

```
    Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
          [enero] => 2 [febrero] => 2 [marzo] => 2 [abril] => 4 [mayo] => 4) 
    [1] => Array ( 
          [enero] => 5 [febrero] => 2 [marzo] => 0 [abril] => 3 [mayo] => 4) 
    [2]=>some other arrays

    )
```

into

```
  Array ([enero] => 2 [febrero] => 2 [marzo] => 2 [abril] => 4 [mayo] => 4) 
  Array ([enero] => 5 [febrero] => 2 [marzo] => 0 [abril] => 3 [mayo] => 4)
  some other arrays
```

I tried this code

```
foreach ($in as $key => $value) {
                    foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
                        $a[$key]=$value;
                    }
                }
```

But it only returns the last array

```
Array ( [enero] => 7 [febrero] => 9 [marzo] => 2 [abril] => 4 [mayo] => 0 )
```

Do you have any idea what i can do? thnks

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: By the way I already know that i just have one variable ($a) to get the new array, but how can I save the other arrays into different variables.

Comment: By simply setting them to new variables? Sounds like you just want to break down each into its own variable. You do have to come up with variables to hold them.

Comment: I've voted to close this as "unclear what you're asking" because your example output is identical to your input data, aside from the input being inside an array. I could achieve your desired output with `foreach ($in as $value) { print_r($value); }`, but I'm sure that's not what you mean. Please clarify.

Comment: your idea is almost right. You don't need the second loop. Check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($in); $i++) {
    ${"single_level_array_" . $i} = $in[$i];
}
```

This will make each of the elements of the array `$in` into an array itself. If there are three elements in `$in`, then you will have `$single_level_array_0`, `$single_level_array_1`, and `$single_level_array_2`.

Comment: Thank you so much guy. I really appreciate you help. That's what I needed

Comment: Sure, no problem, @Maurocrispin, I am glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that `$a`, `$b`, `$c` - new arrays, and `$array` - is your current array, you can do such thing:

```
list($a, $b, $c) = $array;
```

`$a`, `$b`, `$c` now contains internal arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  ${'extracted_' .$key} = $value;
}

var_dump($extracted_0);
var_dump($extracted_1);
.
.
.
```